# If $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ is measurable, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f^n d \mu$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ be a measurable function. Prove:

a) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f^n d \mu$ always exists on $[0,\infty]$.

b) The latter limit is finite iff $\mu\{x \in X : f(x)>1\}=0$.

**I'd like to know if my proof is correct:**

What I did is to separate the limit in three parts:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f^n d \mu= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\{x:f(x)<1\}} f^n d \mu + \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\{x:f(x)=1\}} f^n d \mu+ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\{x:f(x)>1\}} f^n d \mu.$$
For the first limit, I used the result which says that if a sequence $\{g_n\}$ decreases pointwise to $g$ and $\int g_1 < \infty$, then $\int g = \lim \int g_n$. So, since $f^n$ decreases to $0$ on ${\{x:f(x)<1\}}$, the first limit is $0$.

The second limit equals $\mu(X)<\infty$.

For the third limit, since $f^n \to \infty$ on ${\{x:f(x)>1\}}$, by the monotone convergence theorem, it's equal to $\int_{\{x:f(x)>1\}} \infty d \mu$, whis is $0$ if $\mu\{x \in X : f(x)>1\}=0$ and is $\infty$ otherwise.

I also wonder if the double implication in (b) is proved with this.

Comment: all seem right but there is a limit mistake: the second limit doesn't need to equal $\mu(X)$ but its bounded by $\mu(X)$

Comment: The second limit is $\mu(x\in X: f(x)=1)$.

Comment: The second limit is $\mu [f=1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments seem fine to me.

If $\{f>1\}$ has positive $\mu$ measure then
$$\int f^n\,d\mu\geq \int_{\{f>1\}} f^n\,d\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$$
by monotone convergence.

If $\mu(\{f>1\})=0$ then
\begin{aligned}
\int f^n\,d\mu &=\int_{\{f<1\}}f^n\,d\mu +\int_{\{f=1\}}f^n\,d\mu  +\int_{\{f>1\}}f^n\,d\mu \\
&= \int_{\{f<1\}}f^n\,d\mu + \mu(f=1) \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(f=1)
\end{aligned}
again by monotone or dominated convergence.